# Square tiles merging algorithm

Tags: algorithm, tiles

I have an 8x8 square board on which there can be any combination of SQUARE tiles of different colors. These square tiles can be of different sizes, we can have squares of side ranging from 1 to 8, 8 being the max value due to the size of the board.

I need to find an algorithm that allows me to replace square areas of the same color with a square tile as big as the area itself.

See the examples below:

[image: Click here to see an example]

In these examples, we are changing the color of the tile marked with 'x' to yellow in order to obtain a bigger square yellow area. I am looking for an algorithm that will replace the big yellow square area with a corresponding tile of the same size as the area itself (step C). Perhaps the algorithm could start checking for neighboring tiles starting from the tile that we change the color of (the one marked with 'x').

Comment: This reminds me of the octree data structure.

Comment: What if tile X is the corner intersection of two otherwise monochromatic squares?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Good question, I guess which cluster of tiles will "merge" could be determined randomly, or based on the total size of the cluster (i.e. the bigger cluster will merge into one tile).

Comment: And if making the new tile would require another to be split?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat No, splitting other tiles wouldn't be allowed. The only way we can interact with the tiles on the 'board' is by changing the color of 1 tile at a time (as in the case of the tiles marked with 'x' in the examples).

Comment: How fast do you need this to run?  Brute-force should run very quickly, because there are only 9*8*17/6 = 204 possible squares on the board, many of which you don't even need to consider because they don't contain the square you've changed colors for; and each of these 204 squares only contains 64 or fewer 1x1 squares which you can just check the color for; this gives basically a very small multiplier multiplied by 204*64 as an upper bound for the number of operations you need to do with brute force, which is nothing even if you need to do tens of thousands of these moves per second.

Comment: If you want, I'll post the brute-force solution if 10,000 moves per second is good enough for you.  But if you are potentially facing bigger boards and/or want to do more than 10,000 moves per second, there is probably a clever way somebody can post.

Comment: @user2566092 the check needs to run once every 0.2 seconds, so about 5 times per second tops. Thanks for your reply, I am not a sharp mathematical mind but I am trying to wrap my head around your answer and I am starting to see how it could work and be implemented. If I understand it correctly I should check for predefined, square subsets of the 8x8 board array that contain the tile that changed color, and see if they contain tiles of the same color, in which case I would then replace them with a bigger tile of the same size, same color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With such a small board, perhaps we can use brute force. Iterate over the possible squares in descending order of size like so.

```
for (int width = 8; width > 0; width--) {
    for (int x0 = 0; x0 <= 8 - width; x0++) {
        for (int y0 = 0; y0 <= 8 - width; y0++) {
            int x1 = x0 + width;
            int y1 = y0 + width;
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

For each existing square S, test whether the candidate square `[x0, x1] * [y0, y1]` intersects S, and if so, whether it contains S. If S intersects but is not contained, then `[x0, x1] * [y0, y1]` is not a possible replacement. If S is contained but has the wrong color, ditto.

If candidate survives these tests (and contains the changed square, in case the original board has more tiles than it should), then it is placed, and the squares it contains are deleted.

Comment: Thanks for this solution David, i can understand the underlying logic, and it makes perfect sense, I just have to figure out the exact maths to determine whether the candidate square intersect and contains an existing square, which I am sure is a very simple calculation but not having bumped into it before I will have to look into it a bit deeper [feeling very dumb!]

Comment: @Francesco To test whether [x0', x1'] * [y0', y1'] is contained, test whether x0 <= x0' and x1' <= x1 and y0 <= y0' and y1' <= y1. Intersection of squares is more complicated but should be answered.

Comment: Also one way to optimize this algorithm is to only check for candidates of width >= the width of the tile we changed the color of, as this one has to necessarily be included in a possible candidate.